# Задача на reactJS. Бросание кубика

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Задача начального уровня (упражняюсь в react):
Есть компонент, отображающий два кубика (кости). Компонент принимает в props значения по умолчанию для первого и второго кубика:

```
<Dice
  dice1={1}
  dice2={1}
/>
```

Кубики изображены в виде img картинки, которая в src принимает соответствующее значение. По задумке, если в props приходит '1', то нужно отобразить заимпорченную картинку diceIcon1, если '2', то отобразить diceIcon2 и т.д. (до 6).
Я решил сделать через switch (если это не очень хорошее решение, то буду рад критике с пояснениями), но src остаётся пустым, то есть функция не отрабатывает.

PS Дальше хочу сделать "бросание" кубиков по нажатию кнопки, но пока хочу разобраться с дефолтным отображением картинок. Заранее спасибо!

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import Button from './../../components/Button/Component';

import styles from './default.module.scss';

//dice images
import diceIcon1 from './dice-images/dice_1.svg';
import diceIcon2 from './dice-images/dice_2.svg';
import diceIcon3 from './dice-images/dice_3.svg';
import diceIcon4 from './dice-images/dice_4.svg';
import diceIcon5 from './dice-images/dice_5.svg';
import diceIcon6 from './dice-images/dice_6.svg';

class Dice extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const { dice1, dice2 } = this.props;

    this.state = {
      defaultDice1: dice1,
      defaultDice2: dice2
    }
  }

  getDiceImage(dice) {
    switch (dice) {
      case '1': this.setState({dice: diceIcon1}); break;
      case '2': this.setState({dice: diceIcon2}); break;
      case '3': this.setState({dice: diceIcon3}); break;
      case '4': this.setState({dice: diceIcon4}); break;
      case '5': this.setState({dice: diceIcon5}); break;
      case '6': this.setState({dice: diceIcon6}); break;
      default: this.setState({dice: diceIcon1});
    }
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div className={styles['dice']}>
        <div className={styles['dice__holder']}>
          <div className={styles['dice__holder-item']}>
            <img src={this.getDiceImage.bind(this, 'defaultDice1')} alt={''} />
          </div>
          <div className={styles['dice__holder-item']}>
            <img src={this.getDiceImage.bind(this, 'defaultDice2')} alt={''} />
          </div>
        </div>
        <Button
          label={'Бросить кости'}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Dice;
```

Comment: У вас в State ошибка, вы указываете в стэйте одно defaultDice1: dice1,, а передаёте другое dice: diceIcon1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему сам! Через стейт это делать излишне, сделал через отправку пропсы:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import Button from './../../components/Button/Component';

import styles from './default.module.scss';

//dice images
import diceIcon1 from './dice-images/dice_1.svg';
import diceIcon2 from './dice-images/dice_2.svg';
import diceIcon3 from './dice-images/dice_3.svg';
import diceIcon4 from './dice-images/dice_4.svg';
import diceIcon5 from './dice-images/dice_5.svg';
import diceIcon6 from './dice-images/dice_6.svg';

class Dice extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const { dice1, dice2 } = this.props;

    this.state = {
      defaultDice1: dice1,
      defaultDice2: dice2
    }
  }

  getDiceImage(dice) {
    switch (dice) {
      case 1: return diceIcon1;
      case 2: return diceIcon2;
      case 3: return diceIcon3;
      case 4: return diceIcon4;
      case 5: return diceIcon5;
      case 6: return diceIcon6;
      default: return diceIcon1;
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { dice1, dice2 } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className={styles['dice']}>
        <div className={styles['dice__holder']}>
          <div className={styles['dice__holder-item']}>
            <img src={this.getDiceImage(dice1)} alt={''} />
          </div>
          <div className={styles['dice__holder-item']}>
            <img src={this.getDiceImage(dice2)} alt={''} />
          </div>
        </div>
        <Button
          label={'Бросить кости'}
          className={'dice__control'}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Dice;
```